# How to keep status strip visible wherever user scrolls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll, statusbar

I have a form with status strip. Form has auto-scroll on. When required, scrollbars appear and user can scroll.

However when the content is bigger than form size and user has to scroll down to see other parts of the content, he/she has to scroll all the way down also to see the status strip.

I want to keep the status strip on the bottom of the form whatever the size and scroll position is. How do I do that?

**Why can I not put everything on a panel and set `panel.AutoScroll = true`?**

Because I draw everything on this panel (with GDI+), then resize it, then form displays scrollbars. Now if I set autoscroll on in the panel no scroll bars are shown because there are no controls on panel, only GDI+ drawings.

Comment: asp.net? silverlight? WPF? winforms? you need to tell us what platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are doing things backwards.  The "Form" shouldn't be showing the scrollbars, the panel should be.

If the "content" of your panel is larger than your panel, and you are doing all of this drawing inside the panel, then you need to set the panel's `AutoScrollMinSize` to the size of your content, not keep enlarging the size of the panel.

Set the size of your panel's content (example):

```
panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(500, 500);
```

Then in your panel's paint event, apply the transformation:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
  // do your normal painting here
}
```

Use a Double-Buffered panel to avoid flicker.

Your `StatusStrip` should just be docked to the bottom of the form, not interfering with the panel.

Answer (score 3):

Put everything that needs scrolling inside a panel and set auto-scroll on the panel. Your status strip should go outside the panel.

If you are doing extensive drawing with GDI+, there are two good options that I can think of to replace your design.

- If the user must interact with your graphics, consider creating a custom control to encapsulate the functionality and graphics.
- If it is nothing but a display of some data, you can draw your graphics to a Bitmap and view it in a PictureBox.

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, so I can't say what is the correct solution.

Comment: the problem is, I draw everything on a panel and resize it in the end of drawing operation. Form is auto-scrolled therefore scrollbars appear when required. now I can't set auto-scroll on panel because I draw on the panel with GDI+. However I know the total height of the drawing I made on that panel in the end, perhaps somehow I can use it?

Comment: How did you make the Form autoscroll? Were you using GDI+ for drawing the Form?

Comment: I draw everything inside the panel and set panel height. Then since form has autoscroll=true it automatically displays scrollbars. however, I think I will take your second advice. At least, I will experiment.